# Wildcard in string as input

Tags: string, python-3.x, wildcard, filenames

I have a variable that is an input for a process. Its essentially the full path name of a file, but injects a value based on a list to get the correct name:

```
 fipsList = ['06001','06037','06059']
 for fip in fipsList:
     file = r"T:\CCSI\TECH\FEMA\Datasets\NFHL\NFHL_06122018\NFHL_{}_20180518.gdb".format(fip)"
```

What I want to do now is make everything between `"...NFHL_{}_` and `....gdb"` to be a wildcard "*". Simply using `file = r"T:\CCSI\TECH\FEMA\Datasets\NFHL\NFHL_06122018\NFHL_{}_*.gdb".format(fip)"`
doesn't seem to work. Essentially, this is what that produces: 
  `>>>'T:\\CCSI\\TECH\\FEMA\\Datasets\\NFHL\\NFHL_06122018\\NFHL_06_*.gdb'`. Suggestions on how to get it to work?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" how exactly it does not work?

Comment: I'm getting a `file does not exist` error.

Comment: Essentially, this is what that produces: `'T:\\CCSI\\TECH\\FEMA\\Datasets\\NFHL\\NFHL_06122018\\NFHL_06_*.gdb'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding '*' into a string this way will not work. The set up of the question is poor (my own fault), but for clarification's sake, here's how I resolved the issue:

```
 fipsList = ['06001','06037','06059']
 for fip in fipsList:
     path = r"T:\CCSI\TECH\FEMA\Datasets\NFHL\NFHL_06122018"
     for root, dirs, filename in os.walk(path):
        for dir in dirs:
            if('NFHL_' + fip[:2] in dir and '.gdb' in dir):
                file = os.path.join(root, dir)
```

Essentially, I had to walk through the folder and use an `if` conditional to make sure that the conditions of having both the `fip` value and the `.gdb` extension were met.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some old good concat?

Like:

```
fipsList = ['06001','06037','06059']
for fip in fipsList:
    file = "T:\CCSI\TECH\FEMA\Datasets\NFHL\NFHL_06122018\NFHL_{}_" + fip + ".gdb"
```

Comment: Hmmm, that won't really work as the `{}` is getting replaced by the fips. It's the '20180518' that I am looking to replace.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what goes wrong. In case of concat it will do literally what you ask it to do, so it will not modify the first string. I just ran the script, here is the output:    T:\CCSI\TECH\FEMA\Datasets\NFHL\NFHL_06122018\NFHL_{}_06001.gdb
T:\CCSI\TECH\FEMA\Datasets\NFHL\NFHL_06122018\NFHL_{}_06037.gdb
T:\CCSI\TECH\FEMA\Datasets\NFHL\NFHL_06122018\NFHL_{}_06059.gdb

Comment: your code works fine, but it's not the `fip` value that I am trying to inject into the string.